# AutoPostBack of dropdownlist not loading recently changed value

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

Below is my code of Page_Load and SelectedIndexChanged event of dropdownlist(drpdwnshowitems) in which I binded data from database and there is AutoPostBack true as I needed that to do. I am storing recently selected value(item) to a cookie named "NoOfShowItem" and I am requesting that value in page load and want to use but that only gives just previous value. To see that I also displaying that in javascript messagebox that also giving same value. After executing step by step I saw that selectedIndexChanged event was firing after loading(Postback) the page. I searched so much but I couldn't find exact solution for this. so help me anyone please. Thanks in Advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Client_Category : System.Web.UI.Page
{

float countshowitem;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//to see recently selected value
Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">alert('"+
drpdwnshowitems.SelectedValue + "')</script>");
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dtno = ShowItemsFunctions.Select_All_Numbers();
        DataRow dr = dtno.NewRow();
        dr["NoOfProduct"] = "--Select One--";
        dtno.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        drpdwnshowitems.DataSource = dtno;
        drpdwnshowitems.DataTextField = "NoOfProduct";
        drpdwnshowitems.DataValueField = "NoOfProduct";
        drpdwnshowitems.DataBind();

    }

    try
   {
     countshowitem = float.Parse(Request.Cookies["NoOfShowItem"].Value.ToString());
     drpdwnshowitems.SelectedValue = countshowitem.ToString();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       countshowitem = 9;
       drpdwnshowitems.SelectedValue = countshowitem.ToString();
    }
}

protected void drpdwnshowitems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countshowitem = int.Parse(drpdwnshowitems.SelectedValue.ToString());
    Response.Cookies["NoOfShowItem"].Value = drpdwnshowitems.SelectedValue.ToString();
    Response.Cookies["NoOfShowItem"].Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can set the SelectedIndexChanged property dynamically at the end of the Page_Load?

```
drpdwnshowitems.SelectedIndexChanged += drpdwnshowitems_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

As the property is set after the SelectedValue, maybe the event will not fire the first time...

Comment: Thank you Adriien M for your answer, I will try this one. Hope this will work.